# Eclipse RCP error 404 in custom help tab

Tags: java, jsp, eclipse-rcp, embedded-jetty

I want to add some advanced functionality to help browser in an Eclipse RCP application based on Eclipse 3.7. I've created a separate plugin for help functionality and extended org.eclipse.help.webapp.AbstractView:

```
import java.util.Locale;

import org.eclipse.help.webapp.AbstractView;

public class CustomView extends AbstractView {

    @Override
    public String getImageURL() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public char getKey() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "Custom";
    }

    @Override
    public String getTitle(Locale arg0) {
        return "Test Title";
    }

    @Override
    public String getURL() {
        return "/";
    }

    @Override
    public String getBasicURL() {
        return getURL();
    }
}
```

I've added the extension `org.eclipse.help.webapp.view` pointing to this class.

In the same plugin I have a folder plugin/help with file CustomView.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>View Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Hellp JSP!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

This folder is added to build.properties file.

Another tab appears in help contents browser window as expected, but the only thing I get is 404 error inside this tab's frame:

> HTTP ERROR 404
>   Problem accessing /help/CustomView.jsp. Reason:
>
> ```
> /CustomView.jsp
> ```
>
> ---
>
> Powered by Jetty://

What am I doing wrong and how to get this tab contents to display properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the reason this failed. After dissecting the help plugin I've found additional extensions defined that allowed Equinox to use help files supplied in the plugin project as accessible resources. This is what I put in plugin.xml in extensions' section:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.help.webapp.view">
      <view class="plugin.CustomView"></view>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.httpcontexts">
      <httpcontext id="help">
         <resource-mapping path="/"> </resource-mapping>
      </httpcontext>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry.resources">
      <resource alias="/help" base-name="/help" httpcontextId="help"> </resource>
</extension>
```

The firs one is the actual view definition class. Next is the help context pointing on the plugin's root and the last is actual folder containing JSP files, it's position relative to the plugin's root and alias as available for the browser. After adding those Information Center in my application displays my test HTML code in the new tab. The same goes for other extension points in help plugin that add new JSP-based views in Information Center.